# Get input value from text area when clicking a button without using ngModel

Tags: angular

I am trying to get a text areas input value after a user click a button. I need the value in the .ts file.

Here is my code and attempt

```
    <div id="notes-container">
      <label>My Queries</label>
      <textarea id="query" placeholder="Enter here"></textarea>
      <button class="main" (click)="close()"> Back </button>
      <button class="main" (click)="sendQuery($query)"> Send Query </button>
    </div>
```

.ts file

```
console.log(this.query);
```

I currently get no value, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use reference variables like this:

```
<div id="notes-container">
  <label>My Queries</label>
  <textarea #textArea id="query" placeholder="Enter here"></textarea>
  <button class="main" (click)="close()"> Back </button>
  <button class="main" (click)="sendQuery(textArea.value)"> Send Query </button>
</div>
```

But I recommend using [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) for all forms/inputs related stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Use a template variable.

component.html:

```html
<textarea #test>
  test
</textarea>
<button (click)="sendQuery(test)"> Send Query </button>
```

component.ts:

```ts
export class AppComponent  {
  sendQuery(test) { console.log(test.value) }
}
```